# vscode installer download taking so long

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to download vscode installer. I'm trying to get the download file from this link https://code.visualstudio.com/download. However, the download is taking so long and I tried it several times with no success. I strongly believe i don't have any problem with connection since I had checked all my internet connection by downloading atom installer, watching youtube, uploading video & send it via email. Could anyone help me with these.

Is the link obsolete/change?
I'm located in SEA region, is there something to do with region (maybe cdn or something, i'm just guessing)

Thank you

Comment: it takes so long and result in network error

Comment: Did you try from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Comment: Which system are you using?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 20

Comment: @jason I tried using your link, However, same problem. Thank you in advance btw